# Replacing two strings in sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to change lines like this

```
print("hc-takescreenshot: 'this is the description','1'")
print("hc-takescreenshot: 'this is another description','2'")
print("hc-takescreenshot: 'this is yet another description','3'")
```

to this

```
doscreenshot("This is the homepage", "1", self)  
doscreenshot("This is another homepage", "2", self)  
doscreenshot("This is yet another homepage", "3", self)
```

I can do something like this

```
find='print(\"hc-takescreenshot: \x27'
replace='doscreenshot("'
sed -i -e "s/$find/$replace/g" $newpy
```

But that only deals with the first part, I then need to replace the last bit, for example: ,'3'")

What I need to be able to do is extend the replace when the the match is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to keep the `This is...` description strings(it's not clear reading your question), you can try this:

```
sed -i -e "s/.*: '\([^']*\)','\([0-9]*\)'.*/doscreenshot(\"\1\", \"\2\", self)/" "$newpy"
```

Comment: There was a missing double quotes, so is actually like this: sed -i -e "s/.*: '\([^']*\)','\([0-9]*\)'.*/        doscreenshot(\"\1\", \"\2\", self)/" "$newpy" - apart from that it perfectly did what I wanted, so thanks

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, there doesn't seem to be a method for determining what to match and what to replace it with, so you may as well use three distinct `-e 's/…/…/'` argument pairs in a single invocation of `sed`:

```
newpy=data
find='print(\"hc-takescreenshot: '\'
replace='doscreenshot('  # Dropped "
sed -e "s/$find.*1'\")/$replace\"This is the homepage\", \"1\", self)/" \
    -e "s/$find.*2'\")/$replace\"This is another homepage\", \"2\", self)/" \
    -e "s/$find.*3'\")/$replace\"This is yet another homepage\", \"3\", self)/" \
    "$newpy"
```

The `\x27` used in the question didn't work on Mac (with Bash 3); I used `\'` to add a single quote to the end of `find` instead.

However, more intense scrutiny shows that (as well as the function call change) you might want to convert `this` to `This` and `description'` to `homepage"` and the original single-quoted number to a double-quoted number followed by `, self`.  If that's accurate, then you could do that with:

```
find='print(\"hc-takescreenshot: '\'
replace='doscreenshot("'  # Reinstated "
sed -e "/$find/ {" \
    -e "s//$replace/" \
    -e "s/this/This/" \
    -e "s/description'/homepage\"/" \
    -e "s/'\([0-9]\)'\"/ \"\1\", self/" \
    -e "}" \
    "$newpy"
```

The braces group the commands in between so that only lines that match the `$find` are operated on by the 4 substitution commands.  That simplifies the matching.  The `s//$replace/` uses `sed`'s "reuse last regular expression" capability to avoid repeating the match string in the script.

Yes, you could slam all the script into a single `-e` argument if you really like unreadable code and won't be needing to do this more than once.  However, as soon as you find you need to make more than one run, it is better to split things up so that it is readable.  Another option would be to create a file (e.g. `script.sed`) containing the plain `sed` commands (without having to worry about the shell's handling of quotes):

```
/print("hc-takescreenshot: '/ {
   s//doscreenshot("/
   s/this/This/
   s/description'/homepage"/
   s/'\([0-9]\)'"/ "\1", self/
}
```

and you can then run:

```
sed -i.bak -f script.sed "$newpy"
```

For the 3 lines of input shown in the question, all three scripts generate the answer:

```
doscreenshot("This is the homepage", "1", self)
doscreenshot("This is another homepage", "2", self)
doscreenshot("This is yet another homepage", "3", self)
```

<sup>*All code now tested on macOS Sierra 10.12.2 with BSD `sed` and GNU `sed` and Bash 3.2.57(1).*</sup>